# (jQuery after) Returning last insert Object

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to return the new inserted object added by the "after" or "before".

Comment: What is "after" supposed to return? I can try it and see what happens, but that is hardly a contract. I cannot find any mention of the return value in the docs.  http://api.jquery.com/after/  Should I assume that all jquery functions will return "this" unless otherwise documented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly, but [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after) has a friend [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter) and [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before) has a friend [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore), which do the job you're after, although the signature of the methods are reversed.

Where you'd previous have had:

```
target.after(element);
target.before(element);
```

You should now have;

```
element.insertAfter(target);
element.insertBefore(target);
```

Comment: Thank you. I never checked insertAfter before. lIt works fine.

Answer (score 5):

if you do :

```
$('.inner').after('<p>Test</p>');
```

you can get it by :

```
$('.inner').next()
```